# Selenium excel write in row and create additional column and write the value

Tags: excel, selenium

I want to write my data in the row and create column. Please correct the code if incorrect.

I want to write result like this:

[image: this].

But it is not working as expected. Kindly help on this.

```
public void writeExcel(String excelPath,String sheetName,String[] dataToWrite) throws IOException{

    File src = new File(excelPath);
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(src);
    XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
    XSSFSheet sheet1 = wb.getSheet(sheetName);
    int rowCount = sheet1.getLastRowNum()-sheet1.getFirstRowNum();
     //Row row = sheet1.getRow(0);
    //Row newRow = sheet1.createRow(rowCount);
    int colCount = sheet1.getRow(0).getLastCellNum();
    
    System.out.println(rowCount);
     //System.out.println(newRow);
    System.out.println(colCount);


        for(int j = 0; j < colCount; j++){
            
            sheet1.getRow(0).createCell(j+1).setCellValue("Pass");
    
        //    Cell cell = newRow.createCell(j);
            
          //  cell.setCellValue(dataToWrite[j]);

    }



    fis.close();
    
    
    FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(src);
    wb.write(fout);
    wb.close();

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **"for loop"** is a show stopper in your case. It is trying to create **"already present"** first cell in first row as per your code because you are starting j value from 0 and row value also 0.

So here below code might work for you and the for loop will look like :

```
for(int j = 0; j < sheet1.getLastRowNum(); j++){

        sheet1.getRow(0).createCell(colCount).setCellValue("Pass");
}
```